# VBS. Copy files with certain extension to another folder

Tags: vbscript, copy, directory, paste

I have this code:

```
For Each sFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sOriginFolder).Files
If Not oFSO.FileExists(sDestinationFolder & "\" &  oFSO.GetFileName(sFile)) Then
oFSO.GetFile(sFile).Copy sDestinationFolder & "\" & oFSO.GetFileName(sFile),True
End If
Next
```

And I would like to add a condition to say that I just want to copy it when the file is a .txt file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
For Each sFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sOriginFolder).Files
If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(sFile)) = "txt" Then
    If Not oFSO.FileExists(sDestinationFolder & "\" &  oFSO.GetFileName(sFile)) Then
        oFSO.GetFile(sFile).Copy sDestinationFolder & "\" & oFSO.GetFileName(sFile),True
    End If  
End If
Next
```